# Why are P tags not being added to my wordpress posts?

Tags: html, wordpress, paragraph

So I wrote a post in the visual editor as normal. Added some paragraphs with the carriage return as normal, however this is being returned on the page as one long string without any formatting

Here is a page with some text on that should be on different lines...

http://staging.eomfitness.com/uncategorized/test-post/

I am calling 'the_content();' which as far as I know should be formatted

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please show your code that outputs the data to the page - if you use "get_the_content" this actually removed p tags etc and you need to run a function called wpautop() to add them back, see: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop

Comment: Post your template code.

Comment: The only bit thats relevant is  <?php the_content(); ?> , which is what calls the content of the post. Are you saying this doesn't include p tags?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had removed the filter that applies those p tags in my functions file. Sorry to waste your time.

The offending piece of code was...

```
  remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```

... if anyone else is having this problem